# New Git User: Suggested Workflow Help (Specific Example)

Tags: git, workflow

I have read most of the [Progit Book](http://progit.org/book/) and [this tutorial](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/) as well. I think I am getting a very good idea of gits power, its low-cost branching, etc. However, I have a very specific example that I need help with that I think will better help me understand how to bring Git into my workflow.

I have a document with an essay in it. This essay is submitted for scholarship application 1. I created a tag for that commit called "scholarship1" so that when my master branch changes I can always easily reference the version I turned it for that scholarship. I now have a new application for another scholarship (scholarship2). It is very similar but in some what of a different format, so I would have to change around the contents of the essay to match the format.

I am considering making a new branch (called something like scholarship2-version) and working/editing there. Then, when that version is done, merging it back into the master (which I think in my case would just be fast forward merge since Im not actively advancing the master branch) and tagging it as scholarship2. Then I can continue this pattern. That way, if lets say while Im working on scholarship2 application scholarship1 people call me and say "we need you to resubmit with a different font, etc" I can just switch back to master make the changes and resubmit.

I just want to check with you all (thats why I made it a community wiki) to see if there is a better suggested workflow for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either create a new branch for each different version of the essay, or make a duplicate copy of the essay in your working branch.

If you think you are going to want to share changes between multiple versions, then go to the multi-branch route. If each version is going to stand alone after you "branch", then might be better just to copy the essay to a new file. Of course you can still go the multi-branch route, but I'm not sure what you will gain, other than separating the commits between each version of the doc.

Comment: Well this question didn't get much feedback :l